# using functions of non-static class functions in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I have a class containing several functions, and I would like to be able to use functions of these functions. When I try to do something like the code below, I keep getting the compiler error message "invalid use of non-static member function".

```
class MyClass{
    protected:
        void f(int a, int b);
        void g(int num);
        void do_something_with_function(int count, void func(int, int));
        ...
        ...


};

void MyClass::do_something_with_function(int count, void func(int, int)){
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++){
        for(int x=0; x<5; x++){
            for(int y=0; y<3; y++){
                func(x,y);
            }
        }
    }
}

void MyClass::f(int a, int b){
    std::cout<<"a="<<a<<", b="<<b<<std::endl;
}

void MyClass::g(int num){
    do_something_with_function(num, f);
}
```

Is there a way to get this to work without making `f` (and all of the functions on which `f` depends) static?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you just need to accept a pointer to member function, not a regular function.

Change the definition to:

```
void MyClass::do_something_with_function(int count, 
                                         void (MyClass::*func)(int, int)) {
  // ...
  func(1, 2); // and use func
}
```

(and the declaration must be changed as well, of course), and call the function like this:

```
do_something_with_function(num, &MyClass::f);
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3NKSfb).

Comment: thank you, this works for my original question but I just realized I wrote it down wrong. It should have said "func(x,y)" instead. Is there a way to adapt this for this case, so that I can call `do_something_with_function` with arbitrary functions?

Comment: This works for any member function taking 2 ints. I'm not sure what you mean by arbitrary function. Could you show how you plan on using `func` if it could take arbitrary number of parameters?

Comment: Sorry, that was not clear. I meant that `do_something` should ideally be able to handle any of the functions in `MyClass` that take arguments of the form (int, int).

Comment: This solution already does [that](https://godbolt.org/z/WbXUWu) :) Notice that (like your edited question), the solution uses `func` instead of `f`.